# React-Spring - springs with delay get accumulated if the browser tab becomes inactive

Tags: javascript, animation, react-spring

I'm using react-spring for animating my website. I'm using `useSprings` to create multiple springs and add staggered delay for each spring using the index (check below). Everything works fine as expected.

But if I switch to a different tab and come back to my web app, all the delays get expired and all springs start at the same time. How to solve this?

```js
const [circleSprings] = useSprings(dropCount, (i)=> {
    const xPos = Math.random() * w;
    return {
    from: { x: xPos, y: -20 },
    to: { x: xPos, y: h+20 },
    config: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: easings.easeInQuart,
    },
    reset: true,
    delay: i * 500, // delay is staggered here
    loop: true,

}},[]);
```